# Hibernate save is doing update

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate, persistence

Here I'm working on a project that need insert an new audit record to a table.  (e.g. new_vale **vs** old_value),with couple fields that need be updated.

**Problem I'm tryint to solve:**

the **session.save()** is not perform **"INSERT"** but instead it is perform **"UPDATE"**.

```
    private void updateCollabPoApprovaForASN(CollabPoApprovalKey key, PurchaseOrderUpdateASN updateAsn){
       CollabPoApproval collabPoApproval  = this.collabPoApprovalGateway.findById(key);

       compareAndSetChangedValue(updateAsn, collabPoApproval);
       key.setChangeId(generateId());
       collabPoApproval.setKey(key);

       this.collabPoApprovalGateway.save(collabPoApproval);

}
```

Basically, what I did is, I use hibernate query to grab back the existing record , then I modify the primary key by manually set the ID and I update those couple audit fields.  At last, save it back to the DB.

SQL Generated:

```
update CollabPoApproval set OLD_DRAWING_NUMBER=?, NEW_DRAWING_NUMBER=? ... where ID=? and SU_ID=? and PO=? and LINE=?
```

**Background of the table**:

The ID is not auto-increment field, it is a manually generated ID, basically it is a combination of `TimeStamp+[0-999]` (e.g. `20150412113637011`), so I have to manually set it before I save it. 

The table's primary key is a combination of 4 fields including the ID and they are all integers.Besides that, it also including couple dozens other audit fields which i only care about a few.

**Things I have tried that doesn't work:**

Google/StackOverFlow Search and tried different approach.

**1st**
add the following generator(I believe this one is default):

```
<generator class="assigned" />
```

so the hbm composit-id is like following:

```
<composite-id class="CollabPoApprovalKey" name="key">
    <key-property name="Id" column="ID" type="long" />
    <key-property name="suId" column="SU_ID" type="integer" />
    <key-property name="po" column="PO" type="integer" />
    <key-property name="line" column="LINE" type="short" />
    <generator class="assigned" />
</composite-id>
```

**2nd**

Tried use this method `save(String entityName, Object object)` by

```
this.collabPoApprovalGateway.save("CollabPoApproval",CollabPoApproval)
```

don't work

**3rd**

Trid use this method `saveOrUpdate(Object object)`

still don't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to insert the new record then create new object of type CollabPoApproval and copy the values from the selected object instead of modifying it. Hibernate looks into the reference of the object, in this case the reference is not changing that why it is firing update statement instead of insert.

```
CollabPoApproval collabPoApproval  = this.collabPoApprovalGateway.findById(key);
CollabPoApproval collabPoApprovalNew = new CollabPoApproval ();
//copy collabPoApproval values to collabPoApprovalNew 
//do other modification
this.collabPoApprovalGateway.save(collabPoApprovalNew );
```

Comment: Thank you Prerak, This fixed my issue. Another approach that my colleague suggested is to call the evict() the existing record from the session. (haven't had a chance to try it yet), I think it will work.

Comment: Yes..but that will unnecessarily complicate your code.